# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.stars.learnyourhome.DataModel.Subject cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: android

in need to Display Data frome mysql to Listview in android.

```
    ApiService api = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call <Subject> call = api.Getsubject();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Subject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Subject>call, Response<Subject> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                list =(List<Subject>)response.body();
                subjectlist.setAdapter(new 
                 subjectAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list));
            }
        }
```